# Issue with append on Jquery when using .eq()

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class that has a students name. After this I am trying to append an input field to replace the name. It works fine when I am using 0 or 1 etc. I have tried using Parseint but this does not help either. Below is an example of my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".Edit-item-Pencil").click(function(){

         var parentIndex =  $('.Edit-item-Pencil').index(this);

         var parentText =   $('.Edit-item').eq(parentIndex).text();

         var test = parentIndex;


         $('.Edit-item').eq(parentIndex).hide();  
         $('.Edit-item' ).eq(parentIndex).removeClass( ".Edit-item" );
         $(".input-edit:eq(" + test + ")").append( '<input class="form-control" id="name" name="Student-text" type="text"/>' );




      });


 })


  <li> <b>Student Name</b> <a href = "#" class = "Edit-item">Name <div class = "input-edit"></div> <span class = "Edit-item-Pencil"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span> </a></li>

            <li> <b>Student Email </b> <a href = "#" class = "Edit-item">My Email<div class = "input-edit"></div> <span class = "Edit-item-Pencil"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span> </a></li>

            <li><b> Module 0 </b> <a href = "#" class = "Edit-item">My grade<div class = "input-edit"></div> <span class = "Edit-item-Pencil"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> </span> </a></li>
```

Comment: Have you checked if this is meaningful? `var parentIndex =  $('.Edit-item-Pencil').index(this);` I can't guess what you want to do actually by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li> <b>Student Name</b> <span class="Edit-item">Name</span>&nbsp;<span class = "Edit-item-Pencil">Edit</span></li>

 <li> <b>Student Name</b> <span class="Edit-item">Email</span>&nbsp;<span class = "Edit-item-Pencil">Edit</span></li>


 <li> <b>Student Name</b> <span class="Edit-item">Test</span>&nbsp;<span class = "Edit-item-Pencil">Edit</span></li>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".Edit-item-Pencil").click(function(){
        $(this).parent("li").find("span.Edit-item").html('<input class="form-control" id="name" name="Student-text" type="text"/>')
      }); 
 })
```

You can do it easily by `$(this)`, I also had to change your HTML code as you took div inside a tag which is not recommended. Please take a look at working example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/119547/)

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the added clean up works perfectly